# AspectJ Spring AOP pointcut hibernate entity functions

Tags: entity, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, hibernate-entitymanager

How do i pointcut the execution of functions defined in the Hibernate Entities, Which is not created or loaded as spring beans. Couldnt find any help over internet to how to do this.

Is there a way to use spring to point cut hibernate entities.

[This is what I found, but no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576785/how-to-pointcut-hibernate-when-i-use-spring-aop)

Answer (score 0):

With Spring AOP, you cannot do it. Spring AOP is a limited AOP solution that is only *similar* to AspectJ. Spring AOP is less capable than AspectJ in a number of ways:

- Spring AOP supports only a limited subset of the AspectJ pointcuts (only execution type of pointcuts)
- Spring AOP has different semantics compared AspectJ, because it uses dynamic proxies instead of direct bytecode manipulation. With the proxy based solution the Spring AOP uses, advices are not executed when the control flow doesn't leave the proxied object, as when invoking another method in the same object, like `this.someOtherMethod()`
- Spring AOP only works for Spring managed beans. Hibernate entities are not Spring managed beans, so Spring AOP doesn't apply to them.

I encourage you to switch over to native AspectJ to be able to advise Hibernate entites or any other non spring managed beans. Spring supports AspectJ nicely and you should be able to change your configuration to use native AspectJ instead of Spring AOP.